# Generate RFC-2445 VTIMEZONE component for iCalendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, icalendar

I'm currently attempting to understand without much success the implementation of VTIMEZONE component using the [iCalendar gem](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar).

I'm generating an ics formatted event calendar, unfortunately when importing event in Google Calendar (as an example), I'm getting wrong date and time due to the missing VTIMEZONE component in the generated calendar.

Writing down the VTIMEZONE component plain text is not really difficult, but I would like to be generated dynamically depending on a ActiveSupport::TimeZone I set in the application.

I explored several leads without success. The closer I came was to get the TZInfo object using ActiveSupport::TimeZone.find_tzinfo() method. But then how can I get the various component items needed to declare both Daylight and Standard VTIMEZONE component?

Is there any gem existing or can I do it natively using TZInfo. Going through all ruby docs I could find didn't help much. Any advice, leads are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, there is something existing in icalendar that does that.
https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar/blob/master/lib/icalendar/tzinfo.rb

Did not dig deep enough the first time.

```
require 'icalendar/tzinfo'

estart = DateTime.new(2008, 12, 29, 8, 0, 0)
tstring = "America/Chicago"
cal = Calendar.new

tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get(tstring)
timezone = tz.ical_timezone(estart)
cal.add(timezone)

cal.event do
  ...
end

cal.to_ical
```